# Test if notebook is running on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

How can I test if my notebook is running on Google Colab?

I need this test as obtaining / unzipping my training data is different if running on my laptop or on Colab.

Comment: upload and test, i don't think any other way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### For environments using ipython

If you are sure that the script will be run using ipython which is the most typical usage, there is also the possibility to check the ipython interpreter used. I think it is a little bit more clear and you don't have to import any module.

```
if 'google.colab' in str(get_ipython()):
  print('Running on CoLab')
else:
  print('Not running on CoLab')
```

If you need to do it multiple times you might want to assign a variable so you don't have to repeat the `str(get_ipython())`.

```
RunningInCOLAB = 'google.colab' in str(get_ipython())
```

`RunningInCOLAB` is True if run in a Google Colab notebook.

### For environments not using ipython

In this case you have to check ipython is used first, assuming that COLab will always use ipython.

```
RunningInCOLAB = 'google.colab' in str(get_ipython()) if hasattr(__builtins__,'__IPYTHON__') else False
```

Comment: This works if you run IPython, otherwise get_ipython() is undefined and will raise an exception.

Comment: @HervéMignot thanks I should have written more clearly that it works only for ipython

Comment: @HervéMignot I have updated the answer for your specific need

Answer (score 81):

Try importing google.colab

```
try:
  import google.colab
  IN_COLAB = True
except:
  IN_COLAB = False
```

Or just check if it's in sys.modules

```
import sys
IN_COLAB = 'google.colab' in sys.modules
```

Comment: The first try-except solution works in Google Colab when using the IPython way of executing a command `!python foo.py`, but also with `os.system('python foo.py')`. However, the second solution with sys.modules does not work for me.

Answer (score 7):

### Improved Solution for all Python environments

As none of the other answers given here worked for me, and I was not using iPython. I checked the environment variables they use in Colab and thus, the following is best for checking the environment:

```
import os

if os.getenv("COLAB_RELEASE_TAG"):
   print("Running in Colab")
else:
   print("NOT in Colab")
```

Comment: this works universally for me!

Answer (score 6):

you can check environment variable like this:

```
import os
if 'COLAB_GPU' in os.environ:
   print("I'm running on Colab")
```

actually you can print out os.environ to check what's associated with colab and then check the key

Comment: This is the only thing that actually worked for me when the code was imported from a package. It seems google.colab and get_ipython don't really work in that context.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I don't see the environment variable. I'm guessing this no longer appears in the new Colab runtimes.

Answer (score -1):

In a `%%bash` cell, use:

```
%%bash
[[ ! -e /colabtools ]] && exit  # Continue only if running on Google Colab

# Do Colab-only stuff here
```

Or in Python equivalence

```
import os
if os.path.exists('/colabtools'):
  # do stuff
```

Comment: This directory doesn't seem to be present currently.  For now I am using

```
%%bash
!(stat -t /usr/local/lib/*/dist-packages/google/colab > /dev/null 2>&1) && exit
```

but I wonder if there is a different approach that would work for bash.