# How do I know if the Google Colab notebook is using the recourses from the Google Compute Engine VM Instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-colaboratory

I see my Google Computer Linux instance on a seperate terminal window.

I basically followed every single instruction listed over [here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html). I followed step 4 perfectly.

and made a successful connection via SSH linking the Google Compute Instance to a port..

How can I verify in my Google Colab notebook that I'm indeed using the CPU and GPU of that Compute Engine instance? By 'using the CPU and GPU of my Compute Engine instance', what I'm asking is, is there any way to VERIFY that I'm indeed using the hardware of the Compute Engine VM?

I tried printing stats (the commands for which I got from another StackOverflow answer)

```
from psutil import *
!cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

I get

```
cat: /proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory
```

I tried this though:

```
cpu_count()
```

I get

```
4
```

I believe these are the number of cores on my LOCAL machine and NOT the VM instance which I seemed to have connected to without problems.

Comment: The documentation isn't so clear. I want to know how to use GCE with Colab too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `!hostname` in a cell on its own will tell you the name of the host executing your python code (hopefully your local machine and your VM have different-enough names that the output will make it obvious where execution is happening).

Comment: It looks like the execution is taking place on my host machine and not in the VM.. I followed every instruction to the tee.. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Probably you already had a jupyter notebook running on local machine before setting up the ssh tunnel, so ssh couldn't grab the port to listen on it. I recommend you tear down the ssh tunnel, close the local notebook binary, and try again.  Might also be worth your while to simply reboot local machine and then collect all the commands you run in a log to post here if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63519730/11671779) is better:

```py
RunningInCOLAB = 'google.colab' in str(get_ipython())
```