# Conditional pip install in Google Colab / Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

is there any way to conditionally install python packages if the notebook is run in Google Colab vs anywhere else?

For example, if you have a notebook that requires some python package, but only want to `!pip install mypackage` when the notebook is being run in colab, is there some way to test for that? e.g.

```
if current_environment == 'Google Colab':
   !pip install my_packages
```

Answer (score 1):

[I found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581278/test-if-notebook-is-running-on-google-colab). You can look for the colabtools folder.

```
%%bash
[[ ! -e /colabtools ]] && exit  # Continue only if running on Google Colab
# Do Colab-only stuff here
!pip install my_packages
```

Comment: this is useful, however since the cell is executing bash already due to the first line, the pip command should not have "!". Instead: `pip install my_packages`