# How can I check whether the Python interpreter is on Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am writing some code which normally runs on a [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). I have some data on [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive) which I want to use this code to analyze and for this I want to use Colaboratory instead of downloading the data. For this, I have to change some file paths in my code if it's being run on Colaboratory. What condition can I use to check if the code is being run on Colaboratory?

My idea is to use `os.uname()`. This works. I identify whether the interpreter is on my local PC or Raspberry Pi. If it's neither, I can say it's Colaboratory. But is there some parameter that can identify Colaboratory using an `if` statement? (like `if somecondition: PLATFORM=colab`)

```
# Check if using PC or Raspberry Pi
if os.uname().nodename == 'raspberrypi':
    PLATFORM = 'Raspberry Pi'
elif 'sashi' in os.uname().nodename.lower():
    PLATFORM = 'DEV'
else:
    PLATFORM = 'COLAB'

if PLATFORM == 'Raspberry Pi':
    PROJECT_DIR = '/home/pi/Projects'
elif PLATFORM == 'DEV':
    PROJECT_DIR = '/Users/sashi/repos/'
elif PLATFORM == 'COLAB':
    PROJECT_DIR = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/'

def some_function(relative_path):
    for f in os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, relative_path):
        print(f)
        # do something with file
```

The output of `os.uname()` on Colaboratory is

`posix.uname_result(sysname='Linux', nodename='46f38c0b1d62', release='5.15.107+', version='#1 SMP Sat Apr 29 09:15:28 UTC 2023', machine='x86_64')`

Comment: Are you open to solving your problem in a different way, other than detecting the interpreter at runtime and choosing to do different things? Because the typical solution to these issues is having a different "front-end" that is called on different platforms which feeds the correct constants into the main logic. This is dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

*Stealing the [answer from korakot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53581278/test-if-notebook-is-running-on-google-colab)*

Try importing google.colab

```
try:
  import google.colab
  IN_COLAB = True
except:
  IN_COLAB = False
```

Or just check if it's in sys.modules

```
import sys
IN_COLAB = 'google.colab' in sys.modules
```

Comment: If this is a dupe then you should flag as dupe, not copy-paste an existing answer from someone else...

Comment: I also flagged, just for the time being there is also a correct answer here :)

Comment: Thank you. It answers my question. Yes, this question is a duplicate. So closing it.

Comment: I know you are in the process of cleaning up the LLM answers (and thank you for that) - Just a curiosity question, when you look at this one.  I *think* that most of yesterday's answers were from ChatGPT, but this one appears to be Bing Chat - Am I correct?  I received the same answer and link to the other SO answer from Bing Chat, but not from ChatGPT.

Comment: 3.5 turbo is my go-to. This answer has not used and AI, but as I said it is mostly taken from another answer